# SharePoint 2013 Workflow - delay in process and duplicating in history on my work flow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I had delay more than 5 minuets waiting for update status or start workflow

and also have many duplicates in actions like: Log in history - as in following pic

[image: repeat the action]